# Extract sub-string between 2 special characters from one column of Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a Python Pandas DataFrame like this:

```
Name  
Jim, Mr. Jones
Sara, Miss. Baker
Leila, Mrs. Jacob
Ramu, Master. Kuttan
```

I would like to extract only name title from Name column and copy it into a new column named Title. Output DataFrame looks like this:

```
Name                    Title
Jim, Mr. Jones          Mr
Sara, Miss. Baker       Miss
Leila, Mrs. Jacob       Mrs
Ramu, Master. Kuttan    Master
```

I am trying to find a solution with regex but failed to find a proper result.

Comment: How would you like to parse `Lastname, Anna Maria` and `Ramu, Master Kuttan`?

Comment: I would like to parse only name titles. That means sub-string between "," and ''."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [157]: df['Title'] = df.Name.str.extract(r',\s*([^\.]*)\s*\.', expand=False)

In [158]: df
Out[158]:
                   Name   Title
0        Jim, Mr. Jones      Mr
1     Sara, Miss. Baker    Miss
2     Leila, Mrs. Jacob     Mrs
3  Ramu, Master. Kuttan  Master
```

or

```
In [163]: df['Title'] = df.Name.str.split(r'\s*,\s*|\s*\.\s*').str[1]

In [164]: df
Out[164]:
                   Name   Title
0        Jim, Mr. Jones      Mr
1     Sara, Miss. Baker    Miss
2     Leila, Mrs. Jacob     Mrs
3  Ramu, Master. Kuttan  Master
```

Comment: @raja, glad it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [str.extract](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html).

The regexp you are looking for is `(?<=, )\w+(?=.)`. In words: take the substring that is preceded by `,`  (but do not include), consists of at least one word character, and ends with a `.` (but do not include). In future, use an online regexp tester such as [regex101](https://regex101.com/); regexps become rather trivial that way.

This is assuming each entry in the `Name` column is formatted the same way.