# Count how many times a column contains a certain value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, counting

Let's say my dataframe looks like this:

```
   column_name
1  book
2  fish
3  icecream|book
4  fish
5  campfire|book
```

Now, if I use `df['column_name'].value_counts()` it will tell me `fish` is the most frequent value.

However, I want `book` to be returned, since row 1, 3 and 5 contain the word 'book'.

I know `.value_counts()` recognizes `icecream|book` as one value, but is there a way I can determine the most frequent value by counting the amount of times each column cell CONTAINS a certain value, so that 'book' will the most frequent value?

Comment: Technically, as you've stated your question, it should return either "o", since that's the most frequent value, or "i", since that's the value that the most rows contains. If you want python to count word frequencies, you have to tell it what a "word" is, i.e. what the separator is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `Series`:

```
a = df['column_name'].str.split('|', expand=True).stack().value_counts()
print (a)
book        3
fish        2
icecream    1
campfire    1
dtype: int64
```

Or `Counter` with list comprehension with flattening:

```
from collections import Counter

a = pd.Series(Counter([y for x in df['column_name'] for y in x.split('|')]))
print (a)
book        3
fish        2
icecream    1
campfire    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: How about a changing seperator? For example: `0::icecream||1::campfire||2::fish` instead of just `icecream|campfire` ?

Comment: @Boomer Then use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44000278/2901002) solution and change extract to findall instead split.

Comment: @Boomer - for me working `pd.Series(Counter([y for x in df['column_name'].str.findall('(?<=\:\:)\w+(?=||)') for y in x]))`

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! Having such an awesome community, makes programming even more fun :)

Answer (score 4):

## `pd.value_counts`

You can also pass a list to the `value_counts` function.  Note I `join` by `|` then split by `|`.

```
pd.value_counts('|'.join(df.column_name).split('|'))

book        3
fish        2
icecream    1
campfire    1
dtype: int64
```

---

## `get_dummies`

This works because your data is structured with `|` as the separator.  If you had a different separator, pass it to the `get_dummies` call `df.column_name.str.get_dummies(sep='|').sum()`

```
df.column_name.str.get_dummies().sum()

book        3
campfire    1
fish        2
icecream    1
dtype: int64
```

If you want the results sorted

```
df.column_name.str.get_dummies().sum().sort_values(ascending=False)

book        3
fish        2
icecream    1
campfire    1
dtype: int64
```

---

## `pd.factorize` and `np.bincount`

Note that I `join` the entire column and split again.

```
f, u = pd.factorize('|'.join(df.column_name).split('|'))
pd.Series(np.bincount(f), u)

book        3
fish        2
icecream    1
campfire    1
dtype: int64
```

To sort, we can use `sort_values` as we did above.  Or this

```
f, u = pd.factorize('|'.join(df.column_name).split('|'))
counts = np.bincount(f)
a = counts.argsort()[::-1]
pd.Series(counts[a], u[a])

book        3
fish        2
campfire    1
icecream    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `collections.Counter` + `itertools.chain`:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

c = Counter(chain.from_iterable(df['column_name'].str.split('|')))

res = pd.Series(c)

print(res)

book        3
campfire    1
fish        2
icecream    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I like `chain` + 1 from me (-: