# Extract substring between two characters - python DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

What is the meaning of string locator `', \s*([^\.]*)\s*\.'` =?

I have a dataframe identical to [Extract sub-string between 2 special characters from one column of Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44000278/extract-sub-string-between-2-special-characters-from-one-column-of-pandas-datafr)

and want to extract the substring located between `","` and `"."`.  Thanks to the post answer, a way would be as below:

```
In [157]: df['Title'] = df.Name.str.extract(r',\s*([^\.]*)\s*\.', expand=False)

In [158]: df
Out[158]:
                   Name   Title
0        Jim, Mr. Jones      Mr
1     Sara, Miss. Baker    Miss
2     Leila, Mrs. Jacob     Mrs
3  Ramu, Master. Kuttan  Master
```

Although I see the outcome being correct, what is the meaning of `',\s*([^\.]*)\s*\.'`? In particular, what is the meaning of '*' and '\'?

Comment: @JustBaron. The first = symbol was part of the question mark, not the expression =)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the following, match:

- a `,` (comma)
- followed by `\s*` zero or more whitespaces characters (tab, spaces, etc)
- followed by `([^\.])*` zero or more characters that are not a `.` (dot)
- followed by `\s*` zero or more whitespaces characters
- followed by a `\.` (dot)

You can find more about regex in [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

**UPDATE**

As @UnbearableLightness mentioned the character `\` is redundant inside a character set to escape the `.` (dot). A character set is anything defined between `[]`.

Comment: The \ in the character set is escaping the dot, which is of course redundant. A \ will still be matched by the expression.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! :)