# How to extract specific keywords within the frame and extract only that data with in the separators

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column data as follows:

```
abc|frame|gtk|enst.24|pc|hg|,abc|framex|gtk4|enst.35|pxc|h5g|,abc|frbx|hgk4|enst.23|pix|hokg|
abc|frame|gtk|enst.15|pc|hg|,abc|framex|gtk2|enst.59|pxc|h5g|,abc|frbx|hgk4|enst.18|pif|homg|
abc|frame|gtk|enst.98|pc|hg|,abc|framex|gtk1|enst.45|pxc|h5g|,abc|frbx|hgk4|enst.74|pig|hofg|
abc|frame|gtk|enst.34|pc|hg|,abc|framex|gtk1|enst.67|pxc|h5g|,abc|frbx|hgk4|enst.39|pik|hoqg|
```

I want to search and extract specific keywords within the frame and extract only that data with in the separators

Specific keywords are

```
enst.35
enst.18
enst.98
enst.63
```

The expected output is

```
abc|framex|gtk4|enst.35|pxc|h5g|
abc|frbx|hgk4|enst.18|pif|homg|
abc|frame|gtk|enst.98|pc|hg|
NA
```

I tried this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44000278/extract-sub-string-between-2-special-characters-from-one-column-of-pandas-datafr)but was not working effectively

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a regex pattern using the given `keywords` then use [`Series.str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) to find all occurrences of regex in series:

```
import re

keywords = ['enst.35','enst.18','enst.98','enst.63']
pattern = '|'.join([rf'[^,]+{re.escape(k)}[^,]+'for k in keywords])
result = df['col'].str.findall(pattern).str.get(0)
```

---

```
#print(result)

0    abc|framex|gtk4|enst.35|pxc|h5g|
1     abc|frbx|hgk4|enst.18|pif|homg|
2        abc|frame|gtk|enst.98|pc|hg|
3                                 NaN
Name: col, dtype: object
```

You can test the regex pattern [`here`](https://regex101.com/r/0XXuwO/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can try in bashscript as follows:

```
for STRING in enst.35 enst.18 enst.98 enst.63; do
  tr \, \\n < file.txt | grep "$STRING" || echo NA
done
```

Answer (score 0):

With `str.extract` and `str.split(',)` to take the last comma separated value:

```
df['Data2'] = df['Data'].str.extract('(^.*enst.35\|.+?\|.+?\||^.*enst.18\|.+?\|.+?\||^.*enst.98\|.+?\|.+?\||^.*enst.63\|.+?\|.+?\||)', expand=False).str.split(',').str[-1]
```

You could create a list of keywords and do list comprehension as well per another answer.