# search by kewords and extract the phrase within the delimiter

Tags: pandas, bash, awk

I have a column data as follows:

```
abc|frame|gtk|enst.24|pc|hg|,abc|framex|gtk4|enst.35|pxc|h5g|,abc|frbx|hgk4|enst.23|pix|hokg|
abc|frame|gtk|enst.15|pc|hg|,abc|framex|gtk2|enst.59|pxc|h5g|,abc|frbx|hgk4|enst.18|pif|homg|
abc|frame|gtk|enst.98|pc|hg|,abc|framex|gtk1|enst.45|pxc|h5g|,abc|frbx|hgk4|enst.74|pig|hofg|
abc|frame|gtk|enst.34|pc|hg|,abc|framex|gtk1|enst.67|pxc|h5g|,abc|frbx|hgk4|enst.39|pik|hoqg|
```

I want to search and extract specific keywords within the frame and extract only that data with in the separators

Specific keywords are

```
enst.35
enst.18
enst.98
enst.63
```

The expected output is

```
abc|framex|gtk4|enst.35|pxc|h5g|
abc|frbx|hgk4|enst.18|pif|homg|
abc|frame|gtk|enst.98|pc|hg|
NA
```

If match is not found fill with NA in the output columns. There can be multiple occurance of id in the same column, but I want to consider only the first occurance.
I tried this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44000278/extract-sub-string-between-2-special-characters-from-one-column-of-pandas-datafr)but was not working effectively. Can we do this with bash script

Comment: can there be multiple matches in a single row as well?

Comment: @anky Yes, I want to consider only first occurence. The code pulls all the matches

Answer (score 5):

Could you please try following, written and tested in shown samples. Mention all values in variable `values_to_be_searched`  which you want to search in Input_file with `,` delimiter.

```
awk -v values_to_be_searched="enst.35,enst.18,enst.98,enst.63" '
BEGIN{
  FS=","
  num=split(values_to_be_searched,array,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    values[array[i]]
  }
}
{
  found=""
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    for(k in values){
      if(match($i,k)){
        print $i
        found=1
        break
      }
    }
  }
  if(found==""){
    print "NA"
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk -v values_to_be_searched="enst.35,enst.18,enst.98,enst.63" '  ##Creating variable values_to_be_searched which has all the values to be searched in it.
BEGIN{                                            ##Starting BEGIN section of this code from here.
  FS=","                                          ##Setting field separator as comma here.
  num=split(values_to_be_searched,array,",")      ##Splitting variable values_to_be_searched into an array here with delimiter comma.
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){                            ##Running a for loop till value of nu here.
    values[array[i]]                              ##Creating array values which has index as value of array which are the keywords to be searched in Input_file.
  }
}
{
  found=""                                        ##Nullifying found here.
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){                             ##Running a for loop till NF here.
    for(k in values){                             ##Traversing through values array here.
      if(match($i,k)){                            ##If match of value k found in current field then do following.
        print $i                                  ##Printing current field here, looks like a match of keyword is found in current field.
        found=1                                   ##Setting found as 1 here.
        break                                     ##Using break to come out of loop and save some cycles of for loop here.
      }
    }
  }
  if(found==""){                                  ##Checking condition if found is NOT SET then do following.
    print "NA"                                    ##Printing NA here.
  }
}
' Input_file                                      ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 4):

since pandas is tagged, You can try with `str.split` followed by `explode` and then `str.contains` + `reindex` for NaN in missing rows

```
keywords = ['enst.35','enst.18','enst.98','enst.63']

s = df['Column'].str.split(',').explode()
s[s.str.contains('|'.join(keywords))].reindex(df.index)
```

---

```
0    abc|framex|gtk4|enst.35|pxc|h5g|
1     abc|frbx|hgk4|enst.18|pif|homg|
2        abc|frame|gtk|enst.98|pc|hg|
3                                 NaN
Name: Column, dtype: object
```

Note: Replace `Column` in the code with original column name.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
for STRING in enst.35 enst.18 enst.98 enst.63; do
  tr \, \\n < file.txt | grep "$STRING" || echo NA
done
```

Output results in:

```
abc|framex|gtk4|enst.35|pxc|h5g|
abc|frbx|hgk4|enst.18|pif|homg|
abc|frame|gtk|enst.98|pc|hg|
NA
```